# d3 globe - says rotate is not a function

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to make my d3 globe rotatable I have a chunk of code to initiate my globe projection, but when I include a line about rotate, I get an error that "TypeError: d3.geo.azimuthal(...).scale(...).rotate is not a function".

The code chunk is

```
var projection = d3.geo.azimuthal()
    .scale(380)
    .rotate([0, 0])
    .origin([-71.03,42.37])
    .mode("orthographic")
    .translate([380, 400]);
```

I'm including these files:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./d3/d3.geo.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Have I left something out?

Comment: I think you need to add jquery file at very first.

Comment: That didn't make a difference.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no plain `d3.geo.azimuthal()`. You have to specify either `d3.geo.azimuthalEqualArea()` or `d3.geo.azimuthalEquidistant`. That being said, I would have expected the error to be more like this: `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'azimuthal'` than what you reported.

Comment: `d3.geo.azimuthal` was I think an older name, so maybe it still exists as a backward-compatibility thing.  But `rotate` is a relatively newer method, and wouldn't be available in back-compatibility features.

Comment: I think I have the most up to date files attached, though.

Answer (score 0):

try: `rotate = [0, 0, 0]` Which is a rotation abound 3 axis for geographic projections

Comment: I had to write .rotate([0, 0, 0]). Still says "rotate is not a function."

Comment: Sorry, can't help:( ...I happen to have been looking at d3's projections and saw the 3 axis, and thought it was worth a try.